# Flex 3 setSelection with htmlText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, htmltext

In Adobe Flex 3, this causes problems.

```
textArea.setSelection( textArea.htmlText.indexOf( 'testString' ), textArea.htmlText.indexOf( 'testString' ) + 10 );
```

This puts the cursor in the wrong place, because indexOf takes into account the HTML tags, but setSelection does not.

Anyone know how to do this? A simple way is a /<[^>]*>/g regular expression, but this doesn't do the job every time.

Help please!

Andrew

Comment: What if you use text instead of htmlText? textArea.text.indexOf( 'testString' ).  In theory that should give you the same text that 'setSelection' is looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
textArea.setSelection( textArea.text.indexOf( 'testString' ), textArea.text.indexOf( 'testString' ) + 10 );
```

By using the 'text' property instead of 'htmlText', you're removing the html tags.  Also, I wouldn't use 2 index searches, it's not efficient.  Try this:

```
var string:String = 'testString';
var index:int = textArea.text.indexOf(string);
textArea.setSelection(index, index + string.length);
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but Alert.show( textArea.htmlText ) shows the correct html text, Alert.show( textArea.text ) shows a blank string.

Comment: Marking yours as correct, because ideally your answer is absolutely correct. Sorry this took so long!